# RolesAllowed in Quarkus with JWT Authentication always returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, quarkus

I have a method in my controller of `Module X` which should be secured by a `@RolesAllowed` annotation:

```
@GET
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public Response findAllPriceRequests() {
    return Response.ok(serviceX.findAllPrices()).build();
}
```

I have another `Module Y-jwt` which contains an api call to retrieve a Jwt like this:

```
public String generateJwt() {
    Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>(
            List.of("admin")
    );
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600;
    return Jwt.issuer("y-jwt")
            .subject("y-jwt")
            .groups(roles)
            .expiresAt(duration)
            .sign();
}
```

The application.properties file of `Module Y-jwt` contains the following:

```
quarkus.http.port=8082

smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=../jwt/privateKey.pem
smallrye.jwt.path.groups=roles
```

The one from `Module x` contains:

```
quarkus.swagger-ui.always-include=true
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=immo-jwt
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=../jwt/publicKey.pem
smallrye.jwt.path.groups=roles
```

The keys are created in the following way:

```
mkdir jwt
openssl genrsa -out jwt/rsaPrivateKey.pem 2048 -ii
openssl rsa -pubout -in jwt/rsaPrivateKey.pem -out jwt/publicKey.pem
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -inform pem -in jwt/rsaPrivateKey.pem -outform pem -out jwt/privateKey.pem
```

In `Module X` this dependency is added:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In `Module Y-jwt` this one is added:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-jwt-build</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, when I try to execute the GET call of Module X with the JWT of Module Y-jwt, then I get back a 403 Forbidden code. So there must be something wrong, because I think it can authenticate me, but not authorise me to execute the actual method that I want.

What did I do wrong?

UPDATE:
The code to generate my JWT:

```
public String generateJwt() {
    Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>(
            List.of("admin, writer")
    );
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600;
    return Jwt.issuer("y-jwt")
            .subject("y-jwt")
            .groups(roles)
            .expiresAt(duration)
            .sign();
}
```

Comment: I'd doublecheck your jwt looks alright with https://jwt.io/ just to make sure.

Also, there should be some log output explaining what exactly went wrong with the request. Mind finding and posting it?

Comment: {
  "iss": "module-y-jwt",
  "sub": "module-y-jwt",
  "groups": [
    "admin, writer"
  ],
  "exp": 1689526448392,
  "iat": 1689526444,
  "jti": "d7d4bac8-fda3-450b-a196-d7b353b27cca"
}

Comment: @Snappawapa you can find the payload (from jwt.io) of the jwt above. Nothing special if you ask me... Also I do not see any loggings the terminal. Should I add some properties to see those?

Comment: This is the code if you want to have a look at it: https://github.com/Tom-De-Backer/immo-accent/tree/authentication_youtube1

Comment: It all looks correct. Can you confirm JWT token is actually passed as a bearer access token with GET ? I can have a look if you can create a simple reproducer and share a link

Comment: @SergeyBeryozkin Yes, this is the curl request:
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8081/price-request/all' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS...5QoKjBwVjpIYcw'

Comment: @JanD.M., Thanks, I see what the problem is now, you have `.groups(roles)` - it creates a `groups` claim but on the receiving end you are customizing with `smallrye.jwt.path.groups=roles` thus `smallrye-jwt` expects to find a `roles` claim. `groups` is checked by default in the MP-JWT space, so dropping `smallrye.jwt.path.groups=roles` should fix the problem, please check

Comment: Just tried it, but removing the `smallrye.jwt.path.groups=roles` does not resolve the problem...

Comment: @JanD.M. OK, thanks, can you create a test token and paste somewhere please for me to check against this config ?

Comment: Never mind, I can do it myself, will do soon today

Comment: @JanD.M. I've opened a draft PR: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/34786, these tests pass. I've created the keys as described above (though `-ii` parameter in `genRsa` was not used). I feel like some details are missing. After checking your comments above I may have spotted the problem, `"groups": [ "admin, writer" ]` - this is not an array of 2 strings but a single string array. Use either `"groups": [ "admin", "writer"]` (preferred) or `"groups": "admin,writer"` - but in the latter case you'd need to set `smallrye.jwt.groups-separator=,` as ` ` is default in the latter case

Comment: Oh that was indeed the problem. I added the code snippet to the question so you could add the answer :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set roles like this:

```
Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>(
            List.of("admin", "writer")
    );
```

otherwise a single string array is created with this string having 2 comma separated roles. In this case, when `smallrye-jwt` detects that a `groups` (or other claim configured with `smallrye.jwt.groups.path`) claim is an array of strings, it treats each array string as an individual value.

Sometimes a claim representing roles is indeed a single non-array string - in such cases `smallrye-jwt` will split this string by space, but the separator can be configured with `smallrye.jwt.groups-separator`.
HTH